# creating a tls websocket connection

Tags: sockets, websocket, client, tls1.2

I have been trying to write a program that is a websocket client connecting to a wss (tls websocket) endpoint. The problem I am having is that I am getting a bad handshake. What all certificate do I need to create a tls connection? I am asking language non specific just mean general authentication needed and possibly how to generate the files.

Comment: This question is too broad. And there are many questions here and tutorials on the internet which explain this. Please come back if you have specific problems with some code and not just missing a general understanding. Hint: The requirements regarding certificates for TLS in Websockets and for HTTPS are the same.

Comment: how is what certificates does tls require too broad?

Comment: for a client do you only need cert and key, do you need root CAs??

Comment: nvm I know what you mean Steffen lmaoo thanks for the help